# Tell cmake to build static version of the library

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries, lib

Let's consider [CuteLogger](https://github.com/dept2/CuteLogger) CMakeLists.txt, it contains

```
ADD_LIBRARY(${library_target} SHARED ${sources} ${includes})
```

which instructs cmake to build the shared version (.dylib on macOS). I know I can change that to

ADD_LIBRARY(${library_target} STATIC ${sources} ${includes})

and it will produce, instead, the static version (.a on macOS).

Can I tell cmake to build the static version (from the command line) even when CMakeLists.txt ADD_LIBRARY is set to SHARED?

I tried

```
cmake .. -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES=False
```

but that does not seem to work.

Comment: The variable is named [BUILD_SHARED_LIBS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html) and it affects only on `ADD_LIBRARY` calls which specify neither SHARED nor STATIC keywords. If SHARED keyword is specified in `ADD_LIBRARY` call then the library is always built as shared.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to add this `if/else` control flow to your `CMakeLists.txt`

```
if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES)
   ADD_LIBRARY(${library_target} SHARED ${sources} ${includes})
else()
   ADD_LIBRARY(${library_target} STATIC ${sources} ${includes})
endif()
```

And then pass the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES` to cmake from command line:

```sh
cmake .. -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES=False
```

Comment: Instead of using conditionals it is simpler to omit type of the library entirely. In that case the type of the library will be selected according `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` variable.